# Edit without passing id as identifier

Tags: admin-on-rest

Suppose I have a List and and Edit  of items of the following schema:

```
STRING key UNIQUE PRIMARY
STRING value
```

The problem is that when using `admin-on-rest`, the Edit uses the `id` by default to generate the request, if it does not have one, it passes undefined. How can I change that on the `SimpleForm` so it uses another parameter instead of `id` - in  my case, `key` -.

Example of the List and Edit:

```
export const ParamList = props => (
<List title = "All params" { ...props} >
    <Datagrid >
        <TextField source = "key" sortable={false} />
        <TextField source = "value" sortable={false} />
        <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
);


export const ParamEdit = props => (
<Edit title = {< ParamTitle />} { ...props } >
    <SimpleForm >
        <TextInput source = "key" />
        <TextInput source = "value" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit >
);
```

When I send the editing, the following request is made:

```
PUT www.randomurl.com/param/undefined
```

But i wished it was something like:

```
PUT www.randomurl.com/param/<item's key>
```

I have seen that on the [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md#using-another-rest-dialect) that is possible to set customize the requests as a whole. But was thinking if there is something easier, like adding a parameter on `SimpleForm`:

```
export const ParamEdit = props => (
<Edit title = {< ParamTitle />} { ...props } >
    <SimpleForm id={"key"}>
        <TextInput source = "key" />
        <TextInput source = "value" />
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit >
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, the correct and only way to do that is to write a custom `restClient`. See https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiersprimary-keys-for-my-resources